# how to distribute variable value for php readfile?

Tags: php, session, textarea, readfile

i can't figure out how to distribute this value in php

```
<textarea rows="25" cols="40" name="content" style="height: 515px; margin: 0px; width: 411px;margin-top:-15px;">
       <?php $name = $_SESSION['name']; $last = $_SESSION['last']; readfile('script/$name.$lastScript.txt'); ?>
</textarea>
```

what is the correct method for doing this?

if the value of session name is John

and session last is Smith

the readfile must contain ('script/JohnSmithScript.txt')

Comment: The problem is in `readfile('...')`. Single quotes do not substitute the variables from within them. If you use double quotes instead, it should work, since variables are replaced within double quotes. In this case, you may need to wrap your variables in `{ }`, else PHP may try and treat `$name` as an object. E.g. `readfile("script/{$name}.{$lastScript}.txt");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
readfile("script/".$name.$last."Script.txt");
```

or

```
readfile('script/'.$name.$last.'Script.txt');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
readfile('script/'.$name.$lastScript.'.txt');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't add variables within single 's. try

```
readfile('script/'.$name.$last'.Script.txt');
```